# VS2012 Publish Web Wizard

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I am using Windows Remote Desktop (RDP) to connect to my office computer via a Cisco Gateway.  In VS2012, my project is open and I clicked Build/Publish Web menu. The Publish Web wizard window flashed for a second then disappeared. It seems to go behind the main VS2012 and made the main VS2012 go into modal mode.  It does not respond to any mouse or keyboard commands.  I had to use Task Manager to kill it then relaunch it to regain control. This doesn't happen when I am in front of my office computer. I can see the Publish Wizard in front of the main VS2012 window. This doesn't happen to my coworkers who are also telecommuting via RDP.  I tried to look up VS2012 log, but there is no such a log file on my computer.  Windows Application Log doesn't say too much either.  There are 2 devenv.exe *32 in the Task Manager Processes tab.  I killed the one with smaller memory size.  It still wouldn't make the main VS2012 come out of modal mode.  Please help.  Thanks.